# Android: Erro a gravar vídeo usando camera2

Tags: android, vídeo, áudio

Olá! Estou a utilizar Android há pouco tempo para a minha tese e preciso de usar uma app para gravar vídeo com audio durante um certo período de tempo. O código que uso baseia-se neste [exemplo da Google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video).

Para dar algum contexto, antes de correr o código que dá erro, a app apresenta alguns ecrãs que permitem ao utilizador estabelecer alguns parâmetros para serem utilizados mais tarde. Quando a app chega a este ecrã específico, começa a correr como é esperado mas, após alguns segundos, crasha e, se estiver em debug, entra num ciclo de tentar gravar e falha constantemente.

O comportamento que espero aqui é que seja exibida um imagem com uma cruz branca para a qual uma pessoa deve ficar a olhar enquanto a câmara frontal grava o vídeo.

O meu código é o seguinte:

```java
package com.example.filipa.eyetracker;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraMetadata;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Size;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Calibration extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Camera2Video";
    private static final SparseIntArray DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    private static final SparseIntArray INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

    static {
        DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
        DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    static {
        INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 270);
        INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 180);
        INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 90);
        INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 0);
    }

    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION_RESULT = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT = 1;

    private TextureView  mTextureView; //A {@link TextureView} for camera preview.
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice; //A reference to the opened {@link android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice}

    // Handles several lifecycle events on a {@link TextureView}
    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener
            = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
            openCamera(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
            configureTransform(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

        }
    };

    private Size mPreviewSize; //The {@link android.util.Size} of camera preview.
    private Size mVideoSize; //The {@link android.util.Size} of video recording.
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder; //MediaRecorder
    private boolean mIsRecordingVideo; //Whether the app is recording video now
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread; //An additional thread for running tasks that shouldn't block the UI.
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler; //A {@link Handler} for running tasks in the background.
    private Semaphore mCameraOpenCloseLock
            = new Semaphore(1); //A {@link Semaphore} to prevent the app from exiting before closing the camera.

    private int milliseconds;

    //{@link CameraDevice.StateCallback} is called when {@link CameraDevice} changes its status.
    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
            startPreview();
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            if (null != mTextureView) {
                configureTransform(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int i) {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
    };

    private String mCameraId;
    private CameraCharacteristics characteristics;

    private File mVideoFolder;
    private String mNextVideoAbsolutePath;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewBuilder;
    private CameraCaptureSession mPreviewSession; //A reference to the current {@link android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession} for preview.

    private int cdotnumber;
    int[] cdots = {R.drawable.calgelo, R.drawable.calgelo, R.drawable.calgelo};

    /*
     * In this sample, we choose a video size with 3x4 aspect ratio. Also, we don't use sizes
     * larger than 1080p, since MediaRecorder cannot handle such a high-resolution video.
     *
     * @param choices The list of available sizes
     * @return The video size
     */
    private static Size chooseVideoSize(Size[] choices) {
        for (Size size : choices) {
            if (size.getWidth() == size.getHeight() * 4 / 3 && size.getWidth() <= 1080) {
                return size;
            }
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable video size");
        return choices[choices.length - 1];
    }

    /*
     * Given {@code choices} of {@code Size}s supported by a camera, chooses the smallest one whose
     * width and height are at least as large as the respective requested values, and whose aspect
     * ratio matches with the specified value.
     *
     * @param choices     The list of sizes that the camera supports for the intended output class
     * @param width       The minimum desired width
     * @param height      The minimum desired height
     * @param aspectRatio The aspect ratio
     * @return The optimal {@code Size}, or an arbitrary one if none were big enough
     */
    private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height, Size aspectRatio) {
        // Collect the supported resolutions that are at least as big as the preview Surface
        List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
        int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
        int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
        for (Size option : choices) {
            if (option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * h / w &&
                    option.getWidth() >= width && option.getHeight() >= height) {
                bigEnough.add(option);
            }
        }

        // Pick the smallest of those, assuming we found any
        if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
            return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable preview size");
            return choices[0];
        }
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

        /* Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
         SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
         a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
         hide the navigation bar.*/
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calibration);

        mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.texture);
        if (mVideoFolder == null){createVideoFolder();}
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        new CountDownTimer(15000, 3000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                delay(1);

                openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
                startRecordingVideo();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                stopRecordingVideo();
                closeCamera();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public void delay(int seconds){
        milliseconds = seconds * 1000;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        nextDot();           //add your code here
                    }
                }, milliseconds);
            }
        });
    }

    public void nextDot() {
        if (cdotnumber < (cdots.length)) {
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setImageDrawable(getDrawable(cdots[cdotnumber]));
        } else {
            stopRecordingVideo();
            closeCamera();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, PostCalibration.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        cdotnumber++;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        startBackgroundThread();
        if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
            openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
        } else {
            mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }

    /*
     * Starts a background thread and its {@link Handler}.
     */
    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

    /*
     * Stops the background thread and its {@link Handler}.
     */
    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT) {
            if(grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Application will not run without camera services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION_RESULT) {
            if(grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Application will not run without audio permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT) {
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                try {
                    createVideoFileName();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Permission successfully granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Application will not run with storage permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void openCamera(int width, int height) {
            CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
            try {
                mCameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[1];

                // Choose the sizes for camera preview and video recording
                characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId);
                StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

                if (map == null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot get available preview/video sizes");
                }

            /* TODO: Increase camera exposure
            Range<Integer> range1 = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_COMPENSATION_RANGE);
            minExposure = range1.getLower();
            maxExposure = range1.getUpper();
            */

                mVideoSize = chooseVideoSize(map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class));
                mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                        width, height, mVideoSize);

                configureTransform(width, height);
                mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    // Add permission for camera and let user grant the permission
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Calibration.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                                        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT);
                    }
                    cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, null);
                } else {
                    cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, null);
                }

            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // Currently an NPE is thrown when the Camera2API is used but not supported on the
                // device this code runs.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "NullPointerException has occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }

    private void closeCamera() {
        try {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
            closePreviewSession();
            if (null != mCameraDevice) {
                mCameraDevice.close();
                mCameraDevice = null;
            }
            if (null != mMediaRecorder) {
                mMediaRecorder.release();
                mMediaRecorder = null;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.");
        } finally {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Start the camera preview
     */
    private void startPreview() {
        if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            closePreviewSession();
            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);

            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Collections.singletonList(previewSurface),
                    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            mPreviewSession = session;
                            updatePreview();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Unable to setup camera preview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, mBackgroundHandler);

        }catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Update the camera preview. {@link #startPreview()} needs to be called in advance.
     */
    private void updatePreview() {
        if (null == mCameraDevice){
            return;
        }
        try{
            setUpCaptureRequestBuilder(mPreviewBuilder);
            HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPreview");
            thread.start();
            mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e){

        }
    }

    private void closePreviewSession() {
        if (mPreviewSession != null){
            mPreviewSession.close();
            mPreviewSession = null;
        }
    }

    private void setUpCaptureRequestBuilder(CaptureRequest.Builder builder) {
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    }

    /*
     * Configures the necessary {@link android.graphics.Matrix} transformation to `mTextureView`.
     * This method should not to be called until the camera preview size is determined in
     * openCamera, or until the size of `mTextureView` is fixed.
     *
     * @param viewWidth  The width of `mTextureView`
     * @param viewHeight The height of `mTextureView`
     */
    //TODO: Code for configureTransform - don't know if needed
    private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
        if(null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize){
            return;
        }
    }

    private void setUpMediaRecorder() throws IOException{
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

        if (mNextVideoAbsolutePath == null || mNextVideoAbsolutePath.isEmpty()){
            createVideoFileName();
        }
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mNextVideoAbsolutePath);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    }

    private void startRecordingVideo(){
        if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize){
            return;
        }
        try{

            closePreviewSession();
            setUpMediaRecorder();
            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;

            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<>();

            //Set up Surface for the camera preview
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
            surfaces.add(previewSurface);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

            //Set up Surface for the MediaRecorder
            Surface recorderSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
            surfaces.add(recorderSurface);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(recorderSurface);

            /* TODO: Increase the camera exposure
            mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
            exp = (int)(maxExposure * 0.35);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION, exp);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(recordSurface);*/

            //Start a capture session
            //Once the session starts, we can update the UI and start recording
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    mPreviewSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mIsRecordingVideo = true;
                            mMediaRecorder.start();
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                }
            }, mBackgroundHandler);

        } catch (CameraAccessException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void stopRecordingVideo(){
        mIsRecordingVideo = false;
        //Stop recording
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mMediaRecorder.reset();
        mNextVideoAbsolutePath = null;
        startPreview();
    }

    private void createVideoFolder() {
        File movieFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
        mVideoFolder = new File(movieFile, "camera2VideoImage");
        if(!mVideoFolder.exists()) {
            mVideoFolder.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    private void createVideoFileName() throws IOException{
        if (mVideoFolder == null){
            createVideoFolder();
        }

        String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String prepend = "VIDEO_" +"CAL_"+ timestamp + "_";
        File videoFile = File.createTempFile(prepend, ".mp4", mVideoFolder);
        mNextVideoAbsolutePath = videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }


    static class CompareSizesByArea implements Comparator<Size> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
            // We cast here to ensure the multiplications won't overflow
            return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() -
                    (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

No debug surgem alguns erros que ainda não consegui descobrir porque aparecem e que são:

```
E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.aux.packagelist"
E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.camera.privapp.list"
E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.camera.hal1.packagelist"
```

até que, eventualmente, a app falha com o erro fatal:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.filipa.eyetracker, PID: 24592
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
        at com.example.filipa.eyetracker.Calibration.stopRecordingVideo(Calibration.java:590)
        at com.example.filipa.eyetracker.Calibration.nextDot(Calibration.java:260)
        at com.example.filipa.eyetracker.Calibration$4$1.run(Calibration.java:249)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Até agora, já tentei algumas sugestões de pessoas que dominam melhor android até adaptar o meu código até à forma que está agora. No entanto, estes erros continuam a surgir e não sei dizer porquê nem como ultrapassá-los. Agradeço qualquer ajuda/sugestões que me consigam dar. Muito obrigada!

Comment: Olá Ana, seja bem vinda ao SOpt, traduza a sua pergunta, a ideia de ter o SO em português é justamente usarmos o português aqui

Comment: Olá! Obrigada pela dica, não me tinha apercebido. Já traduzi :)

Comment: Pelo que identifiquei, o problema está no seu método nextDot que chama o método stopRecordingVideo. To tentando enxergar se ocorreu algum problema nos [estados do MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#state-diagram). Você está testando em um aparelho físico ou emulado, e qual a API utilizada?

Comment: Olá! Obrigada pela resposta! Estou a testar num aparelho físico com API 28